# Angularjs - nested ng-repeat global index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init, ng-init

I have next template:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="supplier in order.Suppliers" data-ng-init="supplierIndex = $index">
    <div data-ng-repeat="group in supplier.Groups">
         {{something}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And model:

```
$scope.order = {
    Suppliers: [
        {
            Groups: [{ id: 'sss'}, {id: 'ddd'}]
        },
        {
            Groups: [{ id: 'qqqq'}, {id: 'www'}, {id: 'xxx'}]
        },
        {
            Groups: [{ id: 'ooo'}]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to display global group index, so output should be like this:

0
1
2
3
4
5

I know that I can use function that calculate index by passed group id at each place we need to display global group index, but how to accomplish this goal most gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{$index}}` to show group index on your list.

Comment: $index inside inner ng-repeat results to 0 1 0 1 2 0

Comment: Can you try {{$parent.$index}} ?

Answer (score 0):

You can merge groups like this in your controller.

```
 $scope.mergedGroups = [];
  for(var i=0;  i < $scope.order.Suppliers.length;  i++){
    for(var k=0;  k < $scope.order.Suppliers[i].Groups.length;  k++){
       $scope.mergedGroups.push($scope.order.Suppliers[i].Groups[k]);
    }
  }
```

then you can use a single ng-repeat and its done.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="group in mergedGroups" >
    {{group}} {{$index}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your options:

1. `$parent.$index`
2. put supplier index inside supplier object
3. create component `<supplier-info supplier="supplier" index="$index">`

Answer (score 0):

If done only in html:

```
<div data-ng-init="$parent.index = 0" data-ng-repeat="supplier in order.Suppliers">
  <div data-ng-repeat="group in supplier.Groups">
    <span data-ng-init="index=$parent.$parent.index;$parent.$parent.index = $parent.$parent.index + 1;">
      {{index}}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```